# Register with Angular and Symfony No route found for "GET http://localhost:8080/registro/nuevo": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)

Tags: angular, symfony, post, get, jwt

when i try to create a new User using POST from angular seems like symfony take the method like GET but i declared POST and didn't add parameters

angular service

```
CreateUser(body:any){
return this.http.post(environment.url + 'registro/nuevo' , body , {responseType:'text'})
.toPromise().then((res:any)=>{
  console.log(res)
})
```

}

symfony controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/registro/nuevo", name="_nuevo" , methods={"POST"})
 */
public function CreateUser(Request $request , EntityManagerInterface $em , UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder ):Response
{
    $request = $this->transformJsonBody($request);

    $user = new User();

        $user->setUsername($request->get("username"));
        $user->setPassword( $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user , $request->get("password")) );

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response(
            'usuario creado con exito',
            Response::HTTP_OK
        );
}
```

debug:router
i can see POST /registro/nuevo

but when i run
php bin/console router:match /registro/nuevo

None of the routes match the path "/registro/nuevo"

output

Route "a_registrar" almost matches but method "GET" does not match any of the required methods (POST)

thanks for your answer , when i run $ bin/console router:match /registro/nuevo --method POST the output is [ERROR] None of the routes match the path "/registro/nuevo" , in Network shows meghod is POST , problem is not request , problem is Symfony takes the method of that route as GET when i specified POST , this problem start when i created security bundle and i specified routes starting "/api/" in security.yaml , after that only routes start "/api" can be set with POST methods and routes startting witthout "/api" only GET method may be allowed , for the moment i am registering new users with GET methods passing username and btoa(password) and in php

```
$user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user , (base64_decode($password))));
```

but i dont really like that

Comment: Does `bin/console router:match /registro/nuevo --method POST` match?  Use your browser's network debug toolbar to see examine the request being passed to Symfony.  These sorts of mysteries can often just be a typo.

Comment: thanks for your answer , when i run $ bin/console router:match /registro/nuevo --method POST the output is [ERROR] None of the routes match the path "/registro/nuevo" ,

Comment: Curious.  Have you tried the ever popular clearing of the cache?  Does the debug:router look something like: `app_create_user            POST     ANY      ANY    /create/user` ?

Comment: yes i did debug router and shows that api_registronuevo             POST     ANY      ANY    /registro/nuevo  , name is unique

Comment: yes php bin/console cache:clear but no effects

Comment: for the moment i am using GET registro/nuevo/username/btoa(password) and in php $user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user , (base64_decode($password)))); but i dont really like it , i am thinking i am missing some config in security.yaml or routes.yaml

Comment: The router:match command will not be impacted by any security stuff.  Maybe a hidden control code in your route?  Maybe try deleting the entire route annotation, verifying the route is gone and then typing it back in.  Desperate times call for desperate measures.  You could even go so far as to create a new Symfony project and just add the one route.

Comment: The problem is when i follow step by step lexicJWT docs https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/index.rst#configuration     , after define the routes starting in api/ , all the routes do not star with api/ their methods only can be GET even if  I setted in POST and debug:router show me its a POST, its second attempt of project and it happen twice , this is the project ,  https://github.com/christian-cell/Angular-guards_Symfony-JWT    i am pretty sure the problem star after follow the JWT lexics docs .

Comment: I cloned your repo, did a composer install and ran `bin/console router:match /registro/nuevo --method POST` and it matched.  Did not use docker.  No idea why it is failing on your machine.  Maybe your docker config but I don't see how.  I happen to be using PHP 8.1 but I don't think that is a factor.  It would have been nice if you mentioned the use of the nelmio cors bundle, your custom configuration as well as your multiple firewalls.  But router:match does not care about any of that.

Comment: Thank you very much to take the time and clone the repo to try it , I think i have volumenes setted properly , but if you can match the route in your host instead of a container i need to change something , if i discover the i'll post here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what worked for me , is creating another access for the role AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY in security.yaml->access_control

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/registro, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

and a new route in routes.yaml named SecurityController

```
SecurityController:
controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::CreateNewUser
path: /api/registro/nuevo
```

after that my route matched with POST method and finally could register with method POST

[image]

So my conclusion is, if I set a new route that is not defined in access control I only can use that route with GET method , but for the access with role IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY , I only can use this resource with token .